# Возможно ли получение имени объекта класса внутри одного из методов

Tags: c++

К примеру есть класс:

```
class B
{
    void print()
    { 
        std::cout << имя объекта; 
        return; 
    };
}
```

Как в `print()` получить имя объекта так, чтобы результатом вызова:

```
int main( void )
{
    B name;
    name.print();
    return 0;
}
```

Было `name`

Comment: Добавить в объект поле для имени, сохранять в нем имя объекта при создании и потом печатать.

Comment: @VTT хотел как-нибудь иначе способ узнать, без всякой практической ценности

Comment: Ну еще можно написать препроцессор типа QT moc, и запускать его чтобы тот добавлял эти поля автоматически во время компиляции. Или добавить чтение отладочных символов и извлекать из них информацию об имени переменной в исходном коде (ака самопальный reflection).

Comment: Вообще скорее всего вам этого делать и не надо, а если кажется что надо, то настоятельно советую хорошенько задуматься над архитектурой программы. Что-то у вас с ней не так скорее всего

Comment: @koresh Вы абсолютно правы, мне этого не надо делать, но нездоровое любопытство меня не оставляет

Comment: @Totem, а что надо печатать если: `B* namePtr = new B; namePtr->print()`, или `B name; B& nameRef = name; nameRef.print()`, или `void f(B& arg) { arg.print();}; f(B())`